# How to manipulate table rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, css-selectors, alternating

I have several tables on a single page.

I am highlighting every other row as well as styling disabled input non-editable data from CSS.

Below is the code I am using presently.  The effect is columns with editable data are alternating white and gold.  Columns with non-editable data are alternating grey and gold.  ( Enough of a visual indicator as to which columns you are able to edit in this grid, for now. )

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#DEDEBC");
  $("tr:even input").css("background-color", "#DEDEBC");
});
```

css

```
input[disabled='disabled'] {
   text-decoration:none; 
   text-indent:5px; 
   color:#006;
   border:none;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 #666 inset; 
   -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 #666 inset; 
   box-shadow:0 0 0 #666 inset;
}
```

I really only want this behavior on 1 of the tables on the current page I am working on (2nd table), but am not that familiar with jquery.   On other pages, I will need it on 2 or 3 tables out of several.

Another problem is that this code continues the odd-even determination across tables.  If the last row in the previous table was even, the first row in the next table is considered odd, and vice versa.

How can I modify the jQuery to select a specific table?  How can I make it start over with a new table?

Comment: add a class instead of inline, will make it simpler for future interactions like "selected row" styling

Answer (score 2):

Give only the tables you want to color the class `colorize`.
Replace your jQuery code with this:

```
$(function(){
    $('table.colorize').each(function(){
        $('tr:even, tr:even input', this).css("background-color", "#DEDEBC");
    });
});
```

This will only color the tables you define with the class and will reset the even for each table.

Comment: Thnx iambriansreed.  Worked perfectly.